# How do I programatically set the status bar background color for all view controllers in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, frontend, statusbar, appdelegate

Is there a way to programmatically set the status bar background color in the AppDelegate file so that this background color can be applied to all view controllers in a given app?

I found the solution below from another Stack Overflow thread, but the problem is that this code needs to be applied to each and every view controller in the app, which I don't think is a sustainable solution. Thanks.

```
   if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   let app = UIApplication.shared
   let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = app.statusBarFrame.size.height

   let statusbarView = UIView()
   statusbarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   view.addSubview(statusbarView)

   statusbarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   statusbarView.heightAnchor
     .constraint(equalToConstant: statusBarHeight).isActive = true
   statusbarView.widthAnchor
     .constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
   statusbarView.topAnchor
     .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
   statusbarView.centerXAnchor
     .constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

   } else {
      let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: 
   "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
      statusBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   }
```

Comment: *"...but the problem is that this code needs to be applied to each and every view controller in the app..."* My first thought when I read a comment like this is why not just subclass `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use containerView with above properties for each viewcontroller and embed your UIView.
it will be defined and configured once.